# YOURLS redirection not working in NGINX - file downloads instead

Tags: nginx, php, yourls

I am trying to configure [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) for my site. I have configured the virtual host in my nginx and the main application works completely fine. But when clicking a short URL, instead of redirecting to real URL it is actually downloading the file.

I see all the issue is with nginx config file, because the same system was working fine with apache.

This is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#   listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/evry.st/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name evry.st;

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
         if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /?$1 break;
  }

        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
        # For example, return an error code
        #return 418;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~* \.php$ {
         ## FastCGI microcache.
        #include microcache_fcgi.conf;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: Can you try it with the recommended nginx config and see if it improves things? https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/wiki/Nginx-configuration

Comment: As I'm also having the same problem with a new install (Nginx 1.7.4) I thought we might both want to post here https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/issues/1715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOURLS has no `/index.php`. Adapt your `try_files` statement to read:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls-loader.php;
```

This should be unnecessary and can be removed:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /?$1 break;
```